# How do I teach my dog to go potty on command?

Tags: toilet-training, defecation

I have run across several articles detailing how to teach a dog to potty on command, and I would like to teach this to my lab mix. Months ago, I chose the cue word "empty" and said it nearly every time I saw it coming. Then came verbal praise and pats. But even after several moths of this, the command just doesn't stick with her at all. And she's about to come on a road trip eventually and I would prefer that she fully learn the command by then, as she'll be in strange places where I'll want her to "go." Any tips to help this happen? In the meantime, I'll be trying to introduce treats as a reward. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With our lab, we repeated the command word multiple times every time he went to toilet, we didn't just say the word once.  We didn't give any food reward after this, just a happy "good boy".

Even then, the technique doesn't work all of the time and he'll do his business whenever he feels the need to.

Keep persevering, but don't expect this to be learned as quickly as other tricks.